# Passing a string from C to Python, what does the Python server see it as?

Tags: python, c, client-server, python-server-pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a python server to convert recvline to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634821/how-to-get-a-python-server-to-convert-recvline-to-a-string)

I can easily communicate from my C client to my python server. The server can print what my client sends it, but for some reason doesn't see the data type as a string? Why is this?

Comment: over what protocol are you communicating? is it a raw TCP/UDP socket? HTTP?

Comment: localhost socket... I believe tcp

Comment: Nicolas, don't repeat your question.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Should I delete it?